Publishing ASP.NET Core MVC web app Views folder is missing
I'm learning ASP.NET Core MVC after working for years with ASP.NET 4.XX MVC under IIS.
I have created a new ASP.NET Core MVC project - everything seems to be familiar.
Now, I published this project to a folder.
What I am confused about - there are no views in that folder.
However, after I pointed IIS to that folder, web app seems to work as expected.
My question is: HOW does it work? Are views compiled into my DLL or EXE?
Second question: is the .EXE file needed in the publishing folder? It looks like I can remove it and my web app still works fine in IIS.
Thank you.


HOW does it work? Are views compiled into my DLL or EXE?

During deployment, the Views folder structure remains the same, but the view files themselves are usually not included as physical files in the publish package (unless you opt not to precompile views). Instead, they are compiled into assemblies.

is the .EXE file needed in the publishing folder? It looks like I can remove it and my web app still works fine in IIS.

Whether the .EXE file is needed depends on the type of deployment. For an FDD, the .EXE file is not required, but for an SCD, the .EXE file is essential.
More information you can refer to this link: Deployment type.

Thank you for your answer @samwu I still can not understand how my deployed app is working without View files.
Any ideas?

It can be returned by JSON, plain text, file contents, or using custom middleware to handle requests. In a pure API application, controllers usually return data in JSON or other formats, rather than views. This way, the application does not require any view files. Controllers can also return plain text or other types of content without the need for view files. In some cases, you may want to bypass the controller entirely and use custom middleware to handle HTTP requests and responses. Finally, the controller can also return file contents without the need for a view file.
